# How to assign role to linq queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying differentiate the users between the two queries below.  I do not have 'rolename' field in the db server, but I was wondering if it is feasible to group or assign role name to the queries

This is what I have currently come up with for one of the query:

```
public class User : iUser
{
    private cd db;

    public User()
    {
        db = new cd();
    }

    public User(cd context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public UserDetail trial(string username, string password)
    {

        string[] role = new string[] { "trial"};

        var query = (from s in db.Subs
                    join u in db.UserDetails on s.sUID equals u.uID
                    where s.sExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                    select u).FirstOrDefault();

        if (query != null)
        {
            // Build a user and add the appropriate Trial role
            return new UserDetail() { query.uUsername = username, query.uPassword = password, Role = "Trial" };
        }
        else
        {
            // No user was found
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

UserDetail class:

```
public partial class UserDetail
  {
    public UserDetail()
    {
        this.Subs = new HashSet<Subs>();
        this.Trial = new HashSet<Trial_Try>();
    }
    public int uID { get; set; }
    public string uUsername { get; set; }
    public string uPassword { get; set; }
  }
```

Currently, I am experiencing compiling errors for following fields username, password and Role. Error -- "UserDetail does not contain definition for username, password and Role."

I am not sure if this is the correct approach, if anyone could advise me, on this issue, it would be very much appreciated.

The desire output, I am looking for from this method, if that I would like to be able to use this query, to test, for particular role name (e.g. trial), only users which match the trial query can access certain information/page.

Comment: What do you mean "the code is unable to find definition for username, password and Role" ? Are those fields defined in your database table ? What error are you getting ? Please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: Apology for the confusion, I have edited and updated my original post, for further details, which you have requested. UserDetail is model data class, which holds the fields uUsername and uPassword. Many thanks for your response and help. further help much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your "Role" property in the class definition?

Comment: I have posted updated version of my user class with the role property.  Is this correct. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I would hesitate to build your own authentication/authorization system and recommend looking into the Identity/Claims models. Rolling your own can get you in trouble quickly. For example, I wouldn't consider "Trial" to be a role, but a claim of IsTrial=true. Roles are typically lists of groupings that your user can belong in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have the assignment backwards in the initialization:

```
// Build a user and add the appropriate Trial role
return new UserDetail() {
    uUsername = query.uUsername, 
    uPassword = query.uPassword, 
    Role = "Trial" };
```

But without seeing the definition of `UserDetail` it's hard to know for sure.

**EDIT**

OK I see the issue now - no, you cannot dynamically add a property to the `UserDetail` class.  You can either add one to the class definition (and just not map it to the DB) or create *another* class with the `Role` property and link it to the `UserDetail` somehow, but you can't simply add a property like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I have tried changing the assignment statements to this before -- query.uUsername = username.  However, this gives 'Invalid initializer member declarator' error. I happy to post my UserDetail class for further reference.  Many thanks for your help and time.